# WALs getting pilled up - restart_lsn of logical replication not moving in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws-dms, wal, logical-replication

We have a replication setup from AWS RDS PostgreSQL to Kafka. The replication slot's restart_lsn is not moving and WALs keep pilling up.
I tried to remove all the Kafka replications and tried using logical replication and AWS DMS on the same postgreSQL instance, that too doesn't release it's position in WAL,Even though the changes are getting replicated to the target. Why replication slots are holding these WALs?

Comment: Does pg_replication_slots show exactly one entry?

Comment: We have around 12 replication slots there, reatart lsn doesn’t move for all of those. WALs get released all at once we reload the target tables of the replication.

Answer (score 0):

Movement of restart_lsn is based on the feedback lsn sent by logical-client(kafka) confirming that upto which point it received changes from kafka.

In your case check whether the program which updates this lsn to postgres is working properly or not.